# Why can't I verify this certificate chain?

Tags: certificate, openssl

I have three certificates in a chain:

- root.pem
- intermediate.pem
- john.pem

When I examine them using `openssl x509 -in [filename] -text -noout` they look fine, root.pem looks like it is self-signed (Issuer == Subject), and the Subject of each certificate is the Issuer of the next one, as expected.

And indeed I can verify the chain up to the intermediate certificate:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile root.pem root.pem
root.pem: OK
$ openssl verify -CAfile root.pem intermediate.pem
intermediate.pem: OK
```

However, john.pem fails:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -CAfile intermediate.pem john.pem
john.pem: C = CL, [...redacted data...]
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

To the best of my knowledge, this means that openssl is unable to find the issuer for intermediate.pem. Which doesn't make sense since root.pem is indeed the issuer for intermediate.pem.

What am I missing?

---

Edit: I had originally posted an answer saying that root.pem and intermediate.pem should be concatenated in one file, and then one should use this file as the parameter for `-CAfile`. This is WRONG, because this implicitly trusts intermediate.pem, as [Johannes Pille](https://superuser.com/users/168931/johannes-pille) points out. Read the link he posted in my deleted answer: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cryptography-dev/2016-August/000676.html

Comment: Please delete your answer, it is dangerous misinformation!

Comment: @JohannesPille Done, thank you for the information

Comment: Kudos for actually doing it and the quick reaction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have to cat the two certificates together in order to verify them.

If you have the following three certificates:

- root.pem - stores a self-signed certificate.
- intermediate.pem - stores a certificate signed by root.pem
- john.pem - stores a certificate signed by intermediate.pem

And you trust only root.pem, then you would verify `john.pem` with the following command:

```
openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -untrusted intermediate.pem john.pem
```

It you had many intermediates, you could just chain `-untrusted intermediate2.pem -untrusted intermediate3.pem ...`

Comment: This. Is the only right answer.

Comment: I thought that if I had both the Intermediate and Root CA Certificates in the bundle `openssl` would pick those up and verify the certificates. Is there a reason this would be happening? Like, the person who signed the user certificate didn't sign it with the Intermediate but the root, or something?

Comment: The last sentence of this answer is wrong. If you have many intermediates, you need to concatenate them into one intermediate file then use the `untrusted` flag once. Using the untrusted flag multiple times does not work.

Comment: @AjaxLeung - both  multiple `-untrusted` options (in any order) or a single `-untrusted` option pointing to a bundle of intermediates (concatenated in any order) works. This is with OpenSSL version 1.1.1c on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah I was mistaken. I think I just wasn't using the right files at the time I wrote the comment.

Comment: Why can we use `-untrusted` parameter to feed in intermediate certificates? According to the manual, it should be used to feed in "A file of untrusted certificates. The file should contain multiple certificates in PEM format concatenated together." So shouldn't we only use this parameter to feed in the certificate that we do not trust and want to exclude in the trust chain?

Comment: @JingHe - untrusted here doesn't mean distrust; it's a neutral judgement, not a negative judgement. openssl will examine the untrusted certs to see if it can establish trust by some other means. If the intermediate certs provided to `-untrusted` are signed by the root cert, then they'll be trusted. If you want to blacklist a cert, then some other option is needed. I don't know what that option is.

Comment: Beware that I had an issue with verifying the certification trust path because the certificates did not have a binary compatible isssuer / subject field. This TLS specific requirement of binary compatibility is *more strict* than RFC 5280: X.509v3 it seems. I.e. even if you've got the chain and trust store setup correctly, it may *still fail*.

Answer (score 3):

what @antiduh said only works for single intermediate certificate case for me. By adding more than one `-untrusted intermediate.pem` in the command seems not work. Not sure is it related to specific openssl version.

According to the openssl document: [https://linux.die.net/man/1/verify]

> -untrusted file
>
> A file of untrusted certificates. The file should contain multiple certificates

In my case I have a chain like:
`root.pem -> intermediate1.pem -> intermediate2.pem -> john.pem`

by cat intermediate1.pem & intermediate2.pem into a single intermediate-chain.pem file and then run `openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -untrusted intermediate-chain.pem john.pem` works for me.

Also seems the in ca extension you need set `basicConstraints = CA:true` otherwise I still encounter openssl verify report error.